# How can I fix the issue: No module named 'multiselectfield'?

Tags: django

I installed django-multiselectfield successfully but it doesn't work. these steps I did to run the lib:

- pip3 install django-multiselectfield
- INSTALLED_APPS = [
  #...,
  'multiselectfield'
  ]
  also, I did create requirements.txt file but the error didn't go, How can I install this lib successfully

models.py

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
class PlayerName(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='player_name')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


PLAYERS = PlayerName.objects.values_list('name', 'name')


class PlayerBox(models.Model):
    player_name = models.ForeignKey(PlayerName, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='player_box')
    name = MultiSelectField(choices=PLAYERS)
```

**Edit post**

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/abdelhamedabdin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiselectfield'
```

Comment: try running makemigrations and migrate

Comment: I did, and it's installed but the same errors

Comment: according to https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/ I have to put it in installed apps, however, I removed it from it and I get the same error

Comment: i dont think it is supported for python 3.8 and django 3, whats your django version?

Comment: yes, I'm using Django 3.0.7 and Python 3.8

Comment: so, what is the alternative of it? any solution?

Comment: hi, i am facing the same issue have you found an alternative?

Comment: Hi @AvinMathew I forgot that question but I think that I was looking for alternatives of select multiple fields and now I'm always using ManyToMany relationships to get that process done